# Using $where to compare against nested field

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection with documents of the following structure (simplifying it, the numbers are just for example):

> {'a' : 1, 'b' : {'c':2}}

I want to run the following mongodb query:

> {'$where' : 'this.a < this.b.c'}

The above doesn't work.
What is the correct syntax for such a query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue: not all of my collection documents contained the "b" value, and thus I was receiving an error:
`db.alerts.find({$where:"this.a < this.b.c"})
error: {
        "$err" : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined",
        "code" : 16722
}`

Fixed by changing my query to:
`{"b.c":{$exists : true}, $where : "this.c < this.b.c"}`